PowerShell: column FriendlyName from Get-Volume is lost after I specify it in Format-Table
This happens on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.3086]
I need specific fields from Get-Volume. Tried using Format-Table:
PS C:\Users\saukrs> Get-Volume | Format-Table -Property DriveLetter, FriendlyName, FileSystemType, DriveType, OperationalStatus, SizeRemaining, Size

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType OperationalStatus SizeRemaining          Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ----------------- -------------          ----
          E              Unknown        Fixed     OK                 244047036416  244047675392
          C              NTFS           Fixed     OK                    145694720  255405891584
          D              NTFS           Fixed     OK                   1708548096 1000186310656
                         NTFS           Fixed     OK                     86540288     529526784

... but values the FriendlyName column/field are gone.
I expected them to be like in the original content.  Please see drive letters C and D:
PS C:\Users\saukrs> Get-Volume | Format-Table

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
E                        Unknown        Fixed     Healthy      OK                    227.29 GB 227.29 GB
C           pagrindinis  NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     141.2 MB 237.87 GB
D           New Volume   NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                      1.59 GB  931.5 GB
                         NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     82.53 MB    505 MB

Why is that?  And how can this be fixed, please?

You can check what properties are returned by using : Get-Volume | Get-Member

@RetiredGeek, thanks!

The FriendlyName property is not part of the object itself, but part of the default table view for MSFT_Volume instances.
It's just the value of the FileSystemLabel property renamed to FriendlyName, and you can manually recreate it with a calculated property:
Get-Volume |Format-Table Property DriveLetter,@{Name='FriendlyName';Expression='FileSystemLabel'},FileSystemType<#,... and so on #>


Annoyingly, the FileSystemLabel property is renamed to FriendlyName in C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Storage\Storage.format.ps1xml under the Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#MSFT_Volume definition.  Compare the two areas between DriveLetter and FileSystemType.
     <View>
          <Name>VolumeTableView</Name>
          <ViewSelectedBy>
              <TypeName>Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#MSFT_Volume</TypeName>
          </ViewSelectedBy>
          <TableControl>
              <TableHeaders>
                  <TableColumnHeader>
                      <Label>DriveLetter</Label>
                  </TableColumnHeader>
                  <TableColumnHeader>
                      <Label>FriendlyName</Label>
                  </TableColumnHeader>
                  <TableColumnHeader>
                      <Label>FileSystemType</Label>
                  </TableColumnHeader>
                  <TableColumnHeader>
                      <Label>DriveType</Label>
                  </TableColumnHeader>
                  <TableColumnHeader>
                      <Label>HealthStatus</Label>
                  </TableColumnHeader>
                  <TableColumnHeader>
                      <Label>OperationalStatus</Label>
                  </TableColumnHeader>
                  <TableColumnHeader>
                      <Label>SizeRemaining</Label>
                  </TableColumnHeader>
                  <TableColumnHeader>
                      <Label>Size</Label>
                  </TableColumnHeader>
              </TableHeaders>
              <TableRowEntries>
                  <TableRowEntry>
                      <TableColumnItems>
                          <TableColumnItem>
                              <PropertyName>DriveLetter</PropertyName>
                          </TableColumnItem>
                          <TableColumnItem>
                              <PropertyName>FileSystemLabel</PropertyName>
                          </TableColumnItem>
                          <TableColumnItem>
                              <PropertyName>FileSystemType</PropertyName>
                          </TableColumnItem>
                          <TableColumnItem>
                              <PropertyName>DriveType</PropertyName>
                          </TableColumnItem>
                          <TableColumnItem>
                              <PropertyName>HealthStatus</PropertyName>
                          </TableColumnItem>
                          <TableColumnItem>
                              <PropertyName>OperationalStatus</PropertyName>
                          </TableColumnItem>
                          <TableColumnItem>
                              <Alignment>Right</Alignment>
                              <ScriptBlock>
                                  $size = $_.SizeRemaining;
                                  $postfixes = @( "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB" )
                                  for ($i=0; $size -ge 1024 -and $i -lt $postfixes.Length; $i++) { $size = $size / 1024; }
                                  return "" + [System.Math]::Round($size,2) + " " + $postfixes[$i];
                              </ScriptBlock>
                          </TableColumnItem>
                          <TableColumnItem>
                              <Alignment>Right</Alignment>
                              <ScriptBlock>
                                  $size = $_.Size;
                                  $postfixes = @( "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB" )
                                  for ($i=0; $size -ge 1024 -and $i -lt $postfixes.Length; $i++) { $size = $size / 1024; }
                                  return "" + [System.Math]::Round($size,2) + " " + $postfixes[$i];
                              </ScriptBlock>
                          </TableColumnItem>
                      </TableColumnItems>
                  </TableRowEntry>
              </TableRowEntries>
          </TableControl>
      </View>

